# dir /r and output stream in Windows Machine

Tags: windows, stream

We had a challenge today at our cybersec class, and at a point of time (in a Windows Machine via terminal) I found an interesting file with `dir` called `root.txt`

By `more root.txt` I got the output `Look deeper...`, which led me to try `dir /a` to see if something is hidden. However, no result.

After a while, the Prof. gave us a hint to use `dir /r` which had this output:

```
..
05/24/2018  05:25 PM                14 root.txt
                                    137 root.txt:confidential.txt:$DATA
..
```

Someone found out that we can read `confidential.txt` using `more < root.txt:confidential.txt`

What exactly is happening here? And what does `/r` do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NTFS stores a file as a collection of [streams](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364404), which are also called NTFS "attributes". I prefer to use the name "stream" since "attribute" commonly refers to a file-attribute flag in a file's `$STANDARD_INFORMATION` stream, such as "hidden", "system", and "readonly". The two stream types that are commonly used directly by Windows programs are data and index (i.e. `$DATA` and `$INDEX_ALLOCATION`).

An NTFS file always has a default (anonymous) data stream, e.g. "filename::$DATA" or, more simply, just "filename". It can also have alternate (named) data streams, such as "filename:streamname:$DATA". A directory can have named data streams, but not a default one since its anonymous stream is the filename index. The `/r` option of CMD's `dir` command calls [`FindFirstStreamW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364424) and `FindNextStreamW` on each file or directory in a listing in order to list its `$DATA` streams.

An NTFS directory has a `$FILE_NAME` index that's named "$I30", e.g. "dirname:$I30:$INDEX_ALLOCATION". This index is also aliased anonymously, e.g. "dirname::$INDEX_ALLOCATION" or, more simply, just "dirname". It can be listed via [`FindFirstFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418) and `FindNextFile`.

Named indexes over other stream types are also possible. For example, an NTFS volume has reparse-point index in its reserved "$Reparse" directory at "\$Extend\$Reparse:$R:$INDEX_ALLOCATION". Listing this index requires a a specific directory query, so `FindFirstFile` can't be used. [`FindFirstVolumeMountPoint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364426) and `FindNextVolumeMountPoint` list this index in order to search for mount points on the volume, i.e. `IO_REPARSE_TAG_MOUNT_POINT` reparse points that target volume GUID paths.

Comment: the 30 in $I30, is because of I[NDEX_ALLOCATION] => 15 chars * 2 bytes each in UTF16LE = 30

Comment: @evandrix, funny, but no. An index over filenames is named "$I30" because it's an [I]ndex over the `$FILE_NAME` attribute, which is assigned the attribute type code 0x30. For a list of attribute type codes, see [`ATTRIBUTE_RECORD_HEADER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devnotes/attribute-record-header). They didn't continue this scheme for the index over reparse points, else it would be named "$IC0" instead of "$R".

Comment: i so thought it would be yet another case like i18n or l10n :/